# Cycle to previous suggestions in VSCode

Tags: sublimetext3, visual-studio-code

[image]

Hi, is there a way in Visual Studio Code to cycle to suggested keywords even when you already selected one of them (by clicking TAB multiple times)? This is possible in Sublime. In VSCode even with the keybindings of Sublime it does not work.

In the GIF above, in order to cycle through keywords, I pressed TAB several times, after typing 'hel' and 'he'

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not possible to achieve this exact behavior out of the box. Even the [Sublime Text Keymap](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.sublime-keybindings) does not support this. Maybe you want to open a [new issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-sublime-keybindings/issues/new)?
A possible workaround to achieve something similar could be to add custom [keybindings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings). To enable toggling the suggestions via <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> you can add the following to your `keybindings.json`:

```json
{
    "key": "tab",
    "command": "selectNextSuggestion",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && suggestWidgetMultipleSuggestions && suggestWidgetVisible"
},
{
    "key": "shift+tab",
    "command": "selectPrevSuggestion",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && suggestWidgetMultipleSuggestions && suggestWidgetVisible"
}
```

#### Update

Maybe [macros](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=geddski.macros) can solve this. This enables you to chain multiple vscode commands into a single command. Then you can bind this new command to <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Comment: I don't know, even with macros it seems impossible. Basically, because the suggestions are only available when you are typing but not when a suggestion is selected and wrote down.

Answer (score 1):

For those still looking for this capability, it was implemented [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/58871). Set

`"editor.tabCompletion": "on"`

in your settings.json, or change the `Editor: Tab Completions` setting in the UI to enable it.

Answer (score 0):

We can use **user keybindings** to navigate up and down in suggestions available.

There are two default key bindings **selectPrevSuggestion** and **selectNextSuggestion** in vscode which can be used to move up and down in the suggestions list.

First, we have to got to **show default key bindings** from settings and here, we can change selectPrevSuggestion and selectNextSuggestion easily as our wish.

In below screenshot we can see that
[image]

For selectPrevSuggestion it is upArrow by default which can be changed by clicking on it easily to our wish.

Similary, we can change for selectNextSuggestion.